# Struts2 validation framework throws exception with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, hibernate-validator

I am using struts2 with hibernate. I am using struts2 validation framework to validate the form fields. The project uses Hibernate too but I don't want hibernate validation for now as requirement is struts2 validation only when I validate and submit the form It throws exception.

I have inherited both methods i.e strut-default, hibernate-default.
Do I need something to disable Hibernate validation to fix the behavior?

(Note: I am learning struts2 framework so please post with code example if possible).

Here is the struts.xml code:

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
 "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
 "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<package name="default" extends="hibernate-default,struts-default">
<action name="saveOrUpdateUser" method="saveOrUpdate" class="com.tutorials4u.web.UserAction">
<result name="success" type="redirect">listUser</result>
<result name="input">listUser</result>  
</action>
<action name="listUser" method="list" class="com.tutorials4u.web.UserAction">
<result name="success">/register.jsp</result>       
</action>
<action name="editUser" method="edit" class="com.tutorials4u.web.UserAction">
<result name="success">/register.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="deleteUser" method="delete"
        class="com.tutorials4u.web.UserAction">
<result name="success" type="redirect">listUser</result>
</action>
</package>
```

Here is the ActionSupport Code:

```
    public class UserAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private User user = new User();
private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
private UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAOImpl();

public User getModel() {
    return user;
}

public String saveOrUpdate()
{
    userDAO.saveOrUpdateUser(user);
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String list()
{
    userList = userDAO.listUser();
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String delete(){
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)
            ActionContext.getContext().get(
                    ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
    userDAO.deleteUser(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id")));
    return SUCCESS;     
}

public String edit(){
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)
            ActionContext.getContext().get(
                    ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
    user = userDAO.listUserById(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id")));
    return SUCCESS;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public List<User> getUserList() {
    return userList;
}

public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
    this.userList = userList;
}


public void validate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("In validate");
}

}
```

This is the jsp form code:

```
<s:form action="saveOrUpdateUser">
<s:push value="user">
<s:hidden name="id" />
<s:textfield name="name" label="User Name" />
<s:radio name="gender" label="Gender" list="{'Male','Female'}" />
<s:select name="country" list="{'India','USA','UK'}" headerKey=""
        headerValue="Select" label="Select a country" />
<s:textarea name="aboutYou" label="About You" />
<s:checkbox name="mailingList"
        label="Would you like to join our mailing list?" />
<s:submit/>
</s:push>
</s:form>
```

Following is the exception thrown when I run the code:

```
In validate method 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.tutorials4u.dao.UserDAOImpl.listUser(UserDAOImpl.java:23)
at com.tutorials4u.web.UserAction.list(UserAction.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:440)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:279)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the DAOImpl code:

```
public List<User> listUser() {  
    List<User> courses = null;
    try {
        courses = session.createQuery("from User").list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return courses;
}

public void saveOrUpdateUser(User user) {
    try {
        session.saveOrUpdate(user);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public void deleteUser(Long userId){
    try{
        User user = (User) session.get(User.class, userId);
        session.delete(user);
    }catch(Exception e){
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public User listUserById(Long userId){
    User user = null;
    try{
        user = (User) session.get(User.class, userId);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return user;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the method list in UserDaoImpl?

Comment: I have updated code

Comment: So what's null?

Comment: Do a debug and verify if your session isn't null.